# adb wont detect my Samsung Galaxy note 5. I've tried everything

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile, data-retrieval, data-recovery

I recently broke the screen of my locked phone and would like to unlock and recover data by using adb, but it's not detecting my broken Samsung Note 5 or even my replacement Samsung Edge 7.

I've tried:

- kill-server/start-server
- downloading newest usb drivers
- enabling developer mode on both phones (I already had developer mode enabled before I broke my Note 5).
- using original usb cord given inside the box.

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: What happens when you do `adb devices`

Comment: `C:\adb>adb devices      
    List of devices attached    
    
    C:\adb>`  Nothing shows up, its just blank

Comment: A possibility is using Linux, only for test. On linux not need install drivers only add rules to udev, is very easy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be with your computer.Try to use a different computer with adb installed to see what happens.If the problem persists,uninstall your Android SDK and re-install it.

Comment: ah it works on my laptop! thank you! i guess ill just reinstall on my desktop

Answer (score 1):

On my Note 5, adb needs the phone's USB connection set to 'USB Data' not just 'charge' (default) before it will recognize it. Once it sees that permission, abd devices will show the phone as 'unauthorized', I then must allow access for debugging on the phone before it will allow access by tapping 'OK' on the popup dialog on the phone.

You could try booting into recovery mode but I don't think Samsung Galaxy allows access vie adb when in recovery. It may depend on the age of the phone.

So it sounds like the phone may be in 'charge only' mode when USB is connected. Your best bet may be repairing the phone.

Comment: Those are all good suggestions, but I have done all of those things with my Note 5, and ADB doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

I am a user of both android studio and Samsung Galaxy Note 5. I solved my issues just the same as you by generating APK files and transfer it to my note 5.

I just found that the reason is unknown resource settings which means my phone only trust google play and block other app. Have a good day.